# Breaking SQL FOR XML query into specifically named parent elements

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, xsd, for-xml

What I'm trying to do I think is quite easy so if you're familiar with `FOR XML` in SQL Server I'd recommend skipping to the bottom and reading the **bold text part** :)

I'm trying to use the `FOR XML` statement in SQL Server 2005 to achieve the results I need. Currently I have this...

```
SELECT  
    txtReasonTypeID AS [ReasonTypeID]
  ,
    (SELECT 
    [Reason].intReasonID, 
    [Reason].txtReason
    FROM    CST_lnkProfileReason INNER JOIN 
    CST_tblReason AS [Reason] ON CST_lnkProfileReason.intReasonID = [Reason].intReasonID 
    WHERE   CST_lnkProfileReason.intProfileID = @intProfileID
    AND   CST_lnkProfileReason.txtReasonTypeID = [Response].txtReasonTypeID
    ORDER BY Reason.txtReason
    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
    )
  ,
    (SELECT 
    [PulledSupportReason].intReasonID, 
    [PulledSupportReason].txtReason
    FROM    CST_lnkPulledSupportReason INNER JOIN 
    CST_tblReason AS [PulledSupportReason] ON CST_lnkPulledSupportReason.intReasonID = [PulledSupportReason].intReasonID 
    WHERE   CST_lnkPulledSupportReason.intProfileID = @intProfileID
    AND   CST_lnkPulledSupportReason.txtReasonTypeID = [Response].txtReasonTypeID
    ORDER BY [PulledSupportReason].txtReason
    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
    )
FROM    CST_tblReasonTypes AS [Response]
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('ResponseProfile')
```

which is returning the following XML...

```
<ResponseProfile>
  <Response ReasonTypeID="ExampleType">
    <Reason intReasonID="106" txtReason="Call Back - 1"/>
    <Reason intReasonID="147" txtReason="Call Back - 2"/>
    <PulledSupportReason intReasonID="892" txtReason="PS Reason a"/>
    <PulledSupportReason intReasonID="893" txtReason="PS Reason b"/>
  </Response>
   ...more <Response>s
</ResponseProfile>
```

As you can see, `Reason` elements and `PulledSupportReason` elements are coming from the same table although they are separate elements in this query. (Probably a case of bad design) But - **what I want is simple enough, to put a parent element around the `Reason` and `PulledSupportReason` elements** eg...

```
<ResponseProfile>
  <Response ReasonTypeID="ExampleType">
     <Reasons>
        <Reason intReasonID="106" txtReason="Call Back - 1"/>
        <Reason intReasonID="147" txtReason="Call Back - 2"/>
     </Reasons>
     <PulledSupportReasons>  
        <PulledSupportReason intReasonID="892" txtReason="PS Reason a"/>
        <PulledSupportReason intReasonID="893" txtReason="PS Reason b"/>
     </PulledSupportReasons>
  </Response>
   ...more <Response>s
</ResponseProfile>
```

I think I can achieve this using `XML PATH` or `XML EXPLICIT`? Thanks for any assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `FOR XML PATH('....'), ROOT('....')` - with it, you should be able to achieve what you're looking for.

I'm illustrating this for the second subselect - adapt accordingly for the first one:

```
(SELECT 
    [PulledSupportReason].intReasonID, 
    [PulledSupportReason].txtReason
 FROM    
     CST_lnkPulledSupportReason 
 INNER JOIN 
    CST_tblReason AS [PulledSupportReason] ON CST_lnkPulledSupportReason.intReasonID = [PulledSupportReason].intReasonID 
 WHERE   
     CST_lnkPulledSupportReason.intProfileID = @intProfileID
     AND CST_lnkPulledSupportReason.txtReasonTypeID = [Response].txtReasonTypeID
 ORDER BY 
     [PulledSupportReason].txtReason
 FOR XML PATH('PulledSupportReason'), TYPE
) AS 'PulledSupportReasons'
```

This should work, I hope ! (can't really test since I don't have your table at hand to see)

The inner `FOR XML PATH(PulledSupportReason')` defines the innermost XML tag to use, adding an alias to the whole sub select (`AS 'PulledSupportReasons'`) gives that subselect a wrapping XML tag equal to that alias defined.

Comment: I knew it was easy! You sir are a bloody great legend! However, I only needed to add the `AS 'PulledSupportReasons'` etc part after each `SELECT`. I didn't need to use `XML PATH` - that had the effect of doing what I wanted *plus* enclosing each `PulledSupportReason` row in a `<PulledSupportReasons>` tag. Hope you follow me! Thanks :D

Comment: Also - The `XML PATH` option had the effect of breaking the row attributes eg `intReasonID`,`txtReason` into separate elements such as `<intReasonID>106<\intReasonID>`. Still trying to get my head round this `FOR XML` business!

Comment: @El Ronnoco: if you want something to be selected as an attribute in `FOR XML PATH`, add a column alias starting with a @ : `SELECT PulledSupportReason.intReasonID AS '@ReasonID'`